# GCC Optimizes away an if clause which can't be optimized

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

I created a small code showing the error I encountered

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int test(char * flag)
{
    char flagger = *flag;
    printf("test value %d", (int) flagger);
    if (flagger != 0x82)
    {
        exit(3);
    }
    else 
    {
        return 0;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    char flag = 0x82, flag1 = 0x12, flag2 = 0x45;
    //char buf[256];
    test(&flag);
    test(&flag1);
    test(&flag2);
}
```

When compiling the code:
gcc -o tester test.c
or
gcc -o tester test.c -O0

```
The resulting disassembly code for the function test in gdb is:  
Dump of assembler code for function test:
0x0804849b <+0>:    push   ebp
0x0804849c <+1>:    mov    ebp,esp
0x0804849e <+3>:    sub    esp,0x18
0x080484a1 <+6>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
0x080484a4 <+9>:    movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [eax]
0x080484a7 <+12>:   mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-0x9],al
0x080484aa <+15>:   movsx  eax,BYTE PTR [ebp-0x9]
0x080484ae <+19>:   sub    esp,0x8
0x080484b1 <+22>:   push   eax
0x080484b2 <+23>:   push   0x80485c0
0x080484b7 <+28>:   call   0x8048350 <printf@plt>
0x080484bc <+33>:   add    esp,0x10
0x080484bf <+36>:   sub    esp,0xc
0x080484c2 <+39>:   push   0x3
0x080484c4 <+41>:   call   0x8048370 <exit@plt>
End of assembler dump.
```

As you can see, the if gets optimized to a version in which exit is always called.

I tried many things (reverting the conditional, using volatiles, etc.), but I run out of ideas to why this happen.
Help please?

Comment: That's why you should enable your warnings. I got `warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]` on your code.

Comment: On the project and not this small poc, I used -Wall, seemed like I had to use -Wextra for this to show.

Comment: This is also why you should never use the `char` type for storing anything but characters. Use `uint8_t` if you need to store values.

Comment: @EfraimWeiss It seems this warning is added if you use either `-pedantic` or `-Wextra`. Always compile your code as `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra` and you'll save yourself from many bugs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On your system, the range of `char` is `-128` to `+127`. But `0x82` is `130` in decimal. Since `130 > 127`, this test can never succeed.

To fix the code you could use:

```
if ( flagger != '\x82' )
```

or

```
if ( (unsigned char)flagger != 0x82 )
```

Note that the earlier code `char flag = 0x82` is an out-of-range assignment, which is implementation-defined behaviour.  You could consider using `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` for all of these variables.